# How much bandwith does a competitve CS:GO match require?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have recently started playing CS:GO and I use limited usage internet connection. I want to know bandwidth usage a competitive CS:GO match has.

Details,
-Official server competitive match.

-Nothing extra downloaded as I play on default maps and stuff.

-Ping lies between 64 - 200

-match lasts 30-40 minutes

-I play for 1 to 3 hours straight

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

if you are on 64 tick , its around 25KB/s (both up+down).
if you are on 128 tick , its around 70KB/s (both up+down).

1. 64 tick -> 1 hour play -> 87 MB
2. 128 tick -> 1 hour play -> 246 MB

you can use application like

- windows resource monitor
- du meter
- NetLimiter

There are a lot software out there that you can track what resource you are using.

Comment: It also depends on the amount of voice chat going on in-game, so it's hard to say. But these figures should give a base estimate.

Comment: you are right, this also will add data but you can disable this feature and not use it to save data.

Comment: This is cool. so its about 25-50kbps youd say? That frightens me a little bit. my internet struggles to hit 100 sometimes, and if anyone else dares to look at the chrome logo it dips way below 30...